# Recursive relation, and its boundary

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Is there any way to solve $na_{n}=(1+n)a_{n-1}+2n-1$
Or, at least to show $a_{n}<2n\ln(n)$ if $a_{0}=0$

Comment: We do have $a_n \sim 2 n \log n$.  But, depending on $a_0$, it could be above $2 n \log n$.

Comment: It is  $a_0=0$.Edited

Answer (score 0):

We have $\displaystyle \frac{a_n}{n+1}=\frac{a_{n-1}}n+\frac3{n+1}-\frac1n$

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{k+1}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_{k-1}}k+3\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k+\frac3{n+1}-3-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\
\frac{a_n}{n+1}&=a_0+2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\frac {3n}{n+1}\\
a_n&=(n+1)a_0-3n+2(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\\
&=-3n+2(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Well
$$na_n=(n+1)a_{n-1}+2n-1$$
$$\implies (n-1)a_{n-1}=na_{n-2}+2n-3$$
Subtracting them gives
$$na_n-(n-1)a_{n-1}=(n+1)a_{n-1}-na_{n-2}+2$$
$$\iff a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+\frac{2}{n}$$

Noting, of course, that $a_0=0 \implies a_1=1$

Does this help?